# removing an element from xml using saxon xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon

Hi I have an xml like this:

```
<ns1:books><ns2:book category="WEB"><ns3:title lang="en">Learning XML</ns3:title>
<ns3:author>Erik T. Ray</ns3:author><ns3:year>2003</ns3:year><ns3:price>39.95</price>
```

Using Saxon xquery I want to remove the ns3:author element, could anyone let me know how can I do it ?

I know there is a fn:remove(..) method but I don't want to use that as it takes an integer as a 2nd argument

Any complete code will be much appreciated

Also 
with saxon I am facing the error like

Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.StaticError: XQuery syntax error in #...nt-node() external; copy $temp#:
    Unexpected token "$" beyond end of query

and I used the xml

declare namespace soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
declare namespace reg="http://www.mycompany.com/internal/xsd/registrationservice";
declare namespace reg1="http://www.mycompany.com/internal/xsd/registrationtypes";

```
declare variable $RegistrationServiceRequest := <reg:RegistrationServiceRequest><reg1:RegistrationAttributes>       <reg1:Username>fdf</reg1:Username><reg1:Password>passwdfdford1</reg1:Password>      <reg1:Title>Mdfdfr</reg1:Title><reg1:FirstName>fdsfdsfsd</reg1:FirstName>
            </reg1:RegistrationAttributes><reg1:AutoLogin> <reg1:AutoLogin1>trtrtrt</reg1:AutoLogin1></reg1:AutoLogin>
        </reg:RegistrationServiceRequest>;
        copy $temp := $RegistrationServiceRequest 
modify delete node $temp/reg1:AutoLogin
return $temp
```

but when i tried with zorba it worked fine , the only problem is with the saxon and the error is at copy line

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks
S

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a small change to a document, XQuery is not your best choice. You can do it with XQuery update, or you can do it with XSLT. Doing it with XQuery alone is possible, but very cumbersome.

Comment: Hi Michael, If I have xml of 70 lines in length and I just want to delete/add a node which is better with respect to performance is it xquery or xslt ?

Comment: If the input is a DOM and you want to modify it in-situ, probably XQuery update. If the input is lexical XML in a file and the updated document is also lexical XML in a file, probably XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XQuery Update](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/) to do this:

```
copy $n := $data modify delete node $n/ns2:book/ns3:author return $n
```

You can try this example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#JTJCK3mGQJgLav/2uOtgldoTYoM=

Or remove the element by using XQuery Scripting:

```
delete node $data/ns2:book/ns3:author; 
$data
```

You can try this example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#QEuf9N5OLfD87WarBscHKrRrwm0=

Comment: HI wcandillon, thanks for replying, I have edited my probelm desription, could you please have a look at and suggest an answer ?